# Press exact same key in another computer(Replicate Key action)

Tags: java

I have a situation where i want to replicate the action of the keys in another computer in a network. For example if i press "abcd" it should have same effect in the computer connected in network. Similar goes to BACKSPACE and any other keys. I tired using Java robot class but didn't get the exact result. Is there any way using Keylistener or Actionlistener or anything that can do this job ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you use the KeyListener/MouseListener to grab the event locally, and then send the key/mouse codes to the remote machine via the network (Socket), and on the receiving end, use the Robot's method's to generate the same key presses?

The key codes between the KeyListener and the Robot should be the same values, and so you shouldn't have to do any translation between them.

There may be some issues across platforms (say if your source system is Windows, and your destination system is Linux, or some other combination of mismatched OSs), but otherwise I think it should work.

If that doesn't work, can you be more specific about what sorts of problems you're actually running into - e.g. what issues, or sets of keys, or whatever don't seem to translate properly?

Comment: maybe first AntiVirus killed that as KeyLogrer +1

Comment: Doubtable, since (1) it doesn't hook into the system key event loops (it can only see the input given to the app, like any other app), and (2) it would have to match a pattern that the AV already identified as a virus. However, I see your point, and I suppose it wouldn't hurt to turn off AV for a short period for testing and see if your theory applies in this case. Never know.

Comment: I suppose I would also try to debug whether the keys are being received but not repeated at the destination, or whether not all of them were being sent to begin with.

Comment: :-) at begining you probably to test system reserved keys (e.g. F5 - Copy) and similair key_shortcuts